# Sql Server Ignore search on a field if parameter is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am creating a **stored procedure**
**spRegularSearch**  having parameters

```
@sex varchar(1),  
@maritalStatus varchar(20) = null,  
@minage int  = null,  
@maxage int = null,  
@state varchar(50) = null,  
@city varchar(50) = null
```

If all the parameters are not null my code is

```
Select tblQuickRegister.memberId , tblUserLogin.lastLogin , tblQuickRegister.dob,tblPhysicalAttributes.height,
 tblHomeTruth.religion, tblEducation.highestQualification , tblOccupation.occupation, tblPicture.profilePic1
 from tblQuickRegister full outer join tblUserLogin on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblUserLogin.memberId
 full outer join tblPhysicalAttributes on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblPhysicalAttributes.memberId
 full outer join tblHomeTruth on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblHomeTruth.memberId
 full outer join tblEducation on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblEducation.memberId 
 full outer join tblOccupation on  tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblOccupation.memberId 
 full outer join tblPicture on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblPicture.memberId 
 full outer join tblMaritalStatus on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblMaritalStatus.memberId 
 full outer join tblContact on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblContact.memberId 
 where
 tblQuickRegister.sex = @sex
 And tblMaritalStatus.maritalStatus = @maritalStatus 
 And (DATEDIFF(DAY,Convert(date,tblQuickRegister.dob),getdate())/365 >= @minage)
 And (DATEDIFF(DAY,Convert(date,tblQuickRegister.dob),getdate())/365 <= @maxage)
 And tblContact.[state] = @state 
 And tblContact.city = @city
```

I want to remove search on basis of field i.e. 
**ignore [fieldname] = @parameter 
if @parameter is null**
Of course i can achieve this using many if else conditions but is there any easy way to do it?

Comment: `[fieldname] = @parameter or @parameter is null`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a common and duplicate question. You can use below:
add "OR @parameter is null" to all your criteria

```
Select tblQuickRegister.memberId , tblUserLogin.lastLogin , tblQuickRegister.dob,tblPhysicalAttributes.height,
 tblHomeTruth.religion, tblEducation.highestQualification , tblOccupation.occupation, tblPicture.profilePic1
 from tblQuickRegister full outer join tblUserLogin on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblUserLogin.memberId
 full outer join tblPhysicalAttributes on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblPhysicalAttributes.memberId
 full outer join tblHomeTruth on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblHomeTruth.memberId
 full outer join tblEducation on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblEducation.memberId 
 full outer join tblOccupation on  tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblOccupation.memberId 
 full outer join tblPicture on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblPicture.memberId 
 full outer join tblMaritalStatus on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblMaritalStatus.memberId 
 full outer join tblContact on tblQuickRegister.memberId = tblContact.memberId 
 where
 (tblQuickRegister.sex = @sex or @sex is null)
 And (tblMaritalStatus.maritalStatus = @maritalStatus or @maritalStatus is null)
 And ((DATEDIFF(DAY,Convert(date,tblQuickRegister.dob),getdate())/365 >= @minage) or @minage is null)
 And ((DATEDIFF(DAY,Convert(date,tblQuickRegister.dob),getdate())/365 <= @maxage) or @maxage is null)
 And (tblContact.[state] = @state or @state is null)
 And (tblContact.city = @city or @city is null)
```

Comment: Sir i want to ignore search on the basis of one field. Suppose if somebody on the front end entered marital Status as "Single" then your OR will also show other records where it is null. This question is not that simple please re - read.

Comment: So  `(tblMaritalStatus.maritalStatus = @maritalStatus or @maritalStatus is null)` will return the search result or true. ?

Answer (score 1):

One easy way to achieve this would be to add lookup conditions to your `WHERE` clause, which would evaluate to `true` thus not having an effect on the output if your `@parameter` value is null.

```
WHERE CASE WHEN @parameter IS NOT NULL THEN column = @parameter ELSE true END
```

I wouldn't actually recommend this approach, as the optimizer has no idea at planning time whether the `@parameter` will or will not be a null value. A better approach would be to build your query dynamically based on your parameters and append condition to your WHERE clause if it's relevant (parameter is not null).

Latter approach would certainly improve performance of execution.

Comment: Can i use a clause as parameter? consider i store the where clause dynamically and send as parameter. I know i am stupid. But my teacher asked me to use sql stored procedure rather than a plain query.

Comment: Simple trick would be to add `WHERE true` as a static condition to your clause, and then based on your parameters append the string `AND @parameter = value` if the `@parameter` is not null. Then you just need to `EXECUTE` that query you have built in your strin variable. This is all to be done within the stored procedure.

Comment: Thank you sir , your answer was helpful. I upvoted it.