# SQL Query Where clause slows down query

Tags: sql

I use to write query like this:

```
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE COl1 = @Param1 OR @Param1 Is NUll
```

The above use to execute find and a decent speed. But now it takes 17 secs.

If I remove the

```
 OR @Param1 Is NULL
```

It executes less than 1 sec.

```
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE COl1 = @Param1
  Executes less that 1 sec
```

Any idea why the OR @Param1 Is Null would add 16 sec to the execution?

I've been using this style of query for many years and haven't noticed any performance hit.

The query basically is saying give my ALL records if @param1 is null otherwise give me only the records that matach @param1

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What is the execution plan? What indexes do you have defined on that table?

Comment: [MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bartd/2009/05/03/sometimes-the-simplest-solution-isnt-the-best-solution-the-optional-parameter-problem/)  has some interesting information on the performance of queries that are structured similarly to your problem query.    "The first problem is that the OR operators will prevent an efficient index seek-based query plan" from the above link.

Comment: You can read my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35812826/2095534. It's related in some way.

Comment: How does it perform if you order your where clause the other way around (check IS NULL then col1 = @param)

Answer (score 1):

Since you are passing in @Param1 you could take a procedure based approach as outlined in the link in my original comment.  This would look like the following:

```
CREATE PROC getData
@Param1 varchar(255) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    IF(@Param1 IS NULL)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM myTable
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT * 
        FROM myTable
        WHERE COL1 = @Param1
    END;
END;
```

Comment: Which has the added benefit of compiling an execution plan which is optimized for both cases, rather than forcing SQL Server to try to generate an execution plan to accommodate all in one query.  That said, I'd compare the execution plans of the statement both ways, to see what ends up being more optimal.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below and let us know if this helps

```
  SELECT *
  FROM myTable 
  WHERE COl1 = nvl(@Param1,col1) ;
```

By using nvl, the value in it is not parsed first and gets the execution plan which might help performance.